# Error in Veracode Greenlight plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

In eclipse [version 2018-12 (4.10.0)] using the Veracode Greenlight (version 2.8.3) plugin, when I use the context menu on a project or package and select "Open in new Window", I get the following error/warning:

> Expected a parent segment to be IAdapatable to an IProject.
>   But didn't find any projects in the tree path.

There doesn't seem to be any mention of such a problem at the Veracode community forums, nor does there appear to be any mention elsewhere on the web (at least not that duck duck go found).  I have uninstalled and re-installed to no avail, and since this version of eclipse is the most recent version authorized for use by my company, I can't simply go get a newer version.

This problem does not occur when using the "Window/New Window" menu, but then I have to deal with the list of all the same projects and packages that I was trying to avoid by using the context menu.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to resolve this?